# Can a household register online?

Tags: civievent, registration, households

I'm testing CiviCRM for a camp, and some of the families that come to a week of Family Camp are very large (some have 10+ kids). I tried the "Register additional participants" method for a large test family, and it

1. Took forever,
2. Generated massively long email receipts, and
3. Didn't generate any family relationships, shared addresses, etc on the backend. This isn't surprising, but it was depressing to think how much manual cleanup this will require after every single registration.

Household registrations seem to be a good potential solution. I cannot find a mechanism for anyone to act as a household, but some of the settings, such as allowing a household to edit member's addresses, seem to indicate that this is possible.

Is there a way that an external constituent can register a household for an "event" (camp session)?

Comment: Hi there, what CMS are you using? We've been able to create something similar with Drupal webform CiviCRM integration.

Comment: Allan, I should have mentioned that I'm using Drupal. I have gone ahead and tried this. I like webforms much better, but they don't allow using price sets OR duplicate prices/keys? I'm scratching my head on how to build the fees for user-selectable numbers of children.

Comment: @bendodge if you register each child individually on the webform then it will calculate the fees based on the number of participants being registered. If you're still stuck please start a new question giving lots of details so we can help.

Comment: Another option for payment is to create a price set and contribution page based on that price set, and then make this contribution page the confirmation page that users get after submitting the form. This does rely on users to enter the correct number of things to buy.

Comment: @Coleman Webforms with CiviCRM integration do not support Price Sets to allow the complex math needed for multi-person registration. The built-in registration form does support Price Sets but only allows adding 10 additional participants, which is not enough for very large families.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Drupal as your CMS, then the answer is "yes". The drupal [Webform-CiviCRM Integration](https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module allows you to set up a form to register one or more people for any number of events, with full control over creating relationships, sharing addresses, sending a concise email recipt, and customizing the look and feel of your form.

For more information, see the [user manual](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration), or this [how-to video](http://civiteacher.com/video/how-register-multiple-events-webform) from CiviTeacher.

Comment: This solved my specific question of how to allow a Household to register. It still leaves loose ends regarding pricing though, as Webform-CiviCRM Integration cannot calculate complex fees. I will ask a separate question regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

For drupal you can use webform civicrm.  This related discussion may be useful which also talks about alternatives:https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27970.0